# List<Type> Remove

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

Somebody explain to me this:

I am trying to delete items from a list with matching ids contained in another list of strings.

Step 1 is as below:
[image: Step1]

I'm trying to delete Items from myListingSyncIDs where the ListingNumber matches ListingNumbers in lstListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs.

The item at [0] Equals a value from lstListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs, as shown in Step 2:
[image: Step2]

But as shown in Step3: The Remove fails:
[image: Step3]

Then After doing a RemoveAll(func) Step4: The Remove works

[image: Step4]

Somebody explain why the Remove(item) doesn't work, Please ...

Code:

```
        myListingSyncIDs.AddRange(myListingSync.Listings);

        #region Remove Listing References Fetched In The Last 24Hrs
        // Listing References Fetched In The Last 24Hrs
        // These will be excluded to optimise the running of the App.
        // Basically meaning that a complete sync of all listings 
        // will only be done once every 24hrs
        // So that if this is run every hr, it will not slow down the most recent additions
        List<String> lstListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs = DAL.PropertyPortalDAL.GetSahtWebserviceUpdatesIn24Hrs();
        List<P24SyncService.ListingSyncItem> myListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs =
            lstListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs.Select(p => new P24SyncService.ListingSyncItem()
            {
                ListingNumber = p,
                Status = P24SyncService.ListingState.AddedModified
            }).ToList();
        foreach (P24SyncService.ListingSyncItem myLSI in myListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs)
        {
            myListingSyncIDs.Remove(myLSI);
        }

        myListingSyncIDs.RemoveAll(p => lstListingsUpdatedIn24Hrs.Contains(p.ListingNumber));

        #endregion
```

ListingSyncItem is:

```
public partial class ListingSyncItem {

    private string listingNumberField;

    private ListingState statusField;

    /// <remarks/>
    public string ListingNumber {
        get {
            return this.listingNumberField;
        }
        set {
            this.listingNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public ListingState Status {
        get {
            return this.statusField;
        }
        set {
            this.statusField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would not it be better if you could put your code as text instead of screen-shots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, your `ListingSyncItem` type doesn't override `Equals`, so `List<T>.Remove` doesn't know that the item to remove is "equal" to the item in your list.

Simply overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` appropriately (to check for the equality of `ListNumber` and `Status`, presumably, and build a hash code based on those) should fix the problem.

For `RemoveAll`, you're providing a predicate. That doesn't use `ListingSyncItem.Equals`, which is why it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I can't be sure without seeing the definition of ListingSyncItem, but I'm guessing this has to do with the fact that you have two instances referring to the same item.

You know that two different instances with the same ListingNumber refer to the same conceptual object, but the List<> doesn't. By default, .NET knows two objects are identical if they share the same instance, but since you're creating a new ListingSyncItem in your internal lambda function, it's not being removed.

What you should do is implement IEquatable in your ListingSyncItem class and make it return True for two objects with the same ListingNumber. Then List will know to remove the right items from the list.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, it is because you arent overriding the Equals. 
By default, it will check for ref equality. Which, obviously, isnt the case here.

Either override Equals and GetHashCode or use some way of getting the correct reference (lambdas for instance)